# ¿Hay alguna forma automática de quitar todos los Log antes de publicar mi aplicación Android?

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy trabajando con Android Studio y quisiera saber si hay alguna forma automática de eliminar todos los Log que haya olvidado a la largo del código.

Instalé el plugin `Analyze` que tiene opciones como `Code Cleanup...` y `Silent Code Cleanup` he ejecutado ambas opciones pero no sirven para quitar los Log.

Por ejemplo había esto en mi código luego de ejecutar ambas opciones:

```
Log.d(TAG,dataSnapshot.toString());
```

Y otros Log en otras partes.

¿Hay alguna forma de limpiar el código de Logs? Esto aligeraría el funcionamiento de la App final, pues en algunos casos he mostrado Logs con mucho contenido para depurar el código y luego con las prisas he olvidado quitarlos. Creo que una  opción como esta sería muy útil, sobre todo en proyectos con mucho código.

Comment: Me figuro que esperas una respuesta más automatizada pero yo lo que haría es hacer una búsqueda masiva con el IDE de `Log.d` y reemplazarla por `//Log.d` para generar una build de producción.

Comment: No soy un entendido en el tema pero mira a ver si este enlace te pueden ayudar [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40914629/android-studio-delete-all-logs-quickly-from-project)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En realidad no existe una forma automática para eliminar las lineas que imprimen mensajes al `LogCat`, por lo tanto si no deseas que se muestren deberás eliminarlas manualmente.

O simplemente comentarlos, reemplazando en toda tu aplicación

" `Log.`" por " `//Log.`"

Otra forma evitar se muestren mensajes desde la aplicación es crear una clase:

```
public final class Log {

    private static final String NO_MESSAGE = "Exception, message not defined.";

    private static final boolean enableLog = true;

    public static void i(String tag, String string) {
        if (enableLog) {
            if(string == null){
                android.util.Log.i(tag, NO_MESSAGE);
            }else{
                android.util.Log.i(tag, string);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void d(String tag, String string) {
        if (enableLog) {
            if(string == null){
                android.util.Log.d(tag, NO_MESSAGE);
            }else{
                android.util.Log.d(tag, string);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void v(String tag, String string) {
        if (enableLog) {
            if(string == null){
                android.util.Log.v(tag, NO_MESSAGE);
            }else{
                android.util.Log.v(tag, string);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void w(String tag, String string) {
        if (enableLog) {
            if(string == null){
                android.util.Log.w(tag, NO_MESSAGE);
            }else{
                android.util.Log.w(tag, string);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void e(String tag, String string) {
        if (enableLog) {
            if(string == null){
                android.util.Log.e(tag, NO_MESSAGE);
            }else{
                android.util.Log.e(tag, string);
            }
        }
    }           
    public static void super_message(String tag, String string) {
        if (enableLog) {
            if(string == null){
                android.util.Log.e(tag, NO_MESSAGE);
            }else{
                android.util.Log.e(tag, string);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Esta clase la importarías en lugar de:

```
import android.util.Log;
```

y cuando desees que no se muestren los mensajes simplemente cambia el valor de la variable `enableLog` a `false` y genera tu aplicación:

```
private static final boolean enableLog = false;
```

Comment: Una forma muy elegante de resolver el problema! Me la anoto para desarrollos futuros

Comment: Muchas gracias. Me extraña que no exista una herramienta automática que lo haga. Había unos Log por ahí que escribían muchísimo contenido porque los había olvidado. Mi solución mejor ha sido siempre comentarlos inmediatamente cuando termino esa parte del desarrollo pero a veces se olvida. Teniendo en cuenta eso me preocuparé más por irlos quitando. Saludos.

Comment: ¿Qué efecto tiene mantener los Log en la aplicación? ¿Puede generar "ruido" o una sobrecarga de la app? @A.Cedano

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' al final de la pregunta explico el motivo por el que los quiero quitar: *Esto aligeraría el funcionamiento de la App final, pues en algunos casos he mostrado Logs con mucho contenido para depurar el código y luego con las prisas he olvidado quitarlos.* En mi caso hay logs que muestran muchísimo contenido en pantalla, creo que si ese contenido se muestran también en los logs la app va a trabajar más y eso se notará en el rendimiento, incluyendo también la batería que consumirá la app, etc. [¿A qué se debe tu nuevo nick? /]

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' además de lo que comenta A.Cedano sobre consumo y rendimiento, en ocasiones no queremos que otras personas vean en su LogCat la información que imprime la aplicación, saludos.

Comment: Qué interesante lo que comentáis, Jorgesys y @A.Cedano , muchas gracias. No sabía que el LogCat guardaría esta info de debugging. Teniéndolo en cuenta, y dado que mi app está en React Native, he puesto en práctica [eliminar los console.log() si se está en DEV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41909599/1983854). ¡Gracias a los dos!

Comment: Sobre mi nick: es por toda la serie de eventos recientes de cambios de SO, tratando mal a los usuarios y tomando un camino que me parece bastante poco acorde con lo que los usuarios queremos.

Answer (score 3):

Por completar la respuesta de @Jorgesys y utilizando parte de su código:

Si se enfocan los métodos de esta manera:

```
public static void d(String tag, Supplier<String> callback) {
    if (enableLog) {
        String string = callback.get();
        if (string == null) {
            android.util.Log.i(tag, NO_MESSAGE);
        } else {
            android.util.Log.i(tag, string);
        }
    }
}
```

Nos evitaríamos que la expresión que pasemos por parámetro en string se evalúe.

Por ejemplo si la llamamos así:

```
Log.d("TAG", obtenerResultadoFuncionLenta());
```

Aunque tengamos enableLog a false, esa función se evaluaría aunque no se escribiese en el log. Si esa función tardase por cualquier motivo, estaríamos relentizando la aplicación y consumiendo batería innecesariamente.

Sin embargo si la llamamos con la lambda de esta manera:

```
Log.d("TAG", () -> { return obtenerResultadoFuncionLenta() });
```

Esa función solo se evaluaría si enableLog está a true.

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo usar la libreria Timber: https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber
Es fácil de implementar, resuelve fácil lo que necesitas desde tu clase Application con un Timber.DebugTree() y si vas a implementar crashlytics, con otro plant podes mandar log.